# Slim 4 internal redirect, infinity loop

Tags: php, slim, slim-4

After upgrading to Slim v4 I'm trying to replace my simple $app->subRequest call with $app->handle as specified in the [changelog](https://www.slimframework.com/2019/08/01/slim-4.0.0-release.html). However there are no details on how to do this in either the changelog or upgrade guide and my best effort to fix it ends up creating an infinite loop:

```
$app->get("/foo", function (Request $req) use ($app) {
    $uri = $req->getUri();
    $newUri = $uri->withPath("/bar");
    $barReq = $req->withUri($newUri);
    // Here we get stuck in endless loop instead of ending up in the /bar route handler below
    $app->handle($barReq);
});

$app->get("/bar", function (Request $req) use ($app) {
    echo 'bar!';
    die;
});
```

It's like even though $barReq is a new request object with a completely new uri (and path) the router does not resolve which route handler that should handle it, instead it's just handled by the same one again.

My previous simplified (v3) code looked like and worked fine to get the result of the /bar route when calling /foo:

```
$app->get("/foo", function (Request $req) use ($app) {
    $app->subRequest('GET', '/bar');
});
```

I'm probably missing some central concept on how Slim 4 handles requests and routes internally and would appreciate some help!

Edit: Should perhaps add that what I mean with internal redirect is that client should not be aware that a redirect has been made. I.e. any regular redirect function returning something to client is not applicable here.

Comment: Have you tried to return the response? e.g. `return $app->handle($barReq);`. Also `die;` is problematic here because it will stop everything. Additionally make sure your "bar" route returns a response object.

Comment: Would it work if you create a new request object, rather than a copy of the existing one and set `$newUri` onto that object?

Comment: @odan Returning does not do any difference. Also infinity loop. The die() instead of returned response object works fine for the limited test here - in any case it's never reached anyway due to the "/bar" route handler never being called.

Comment: @Remy not sure, this is my first time working with PSR7 request/response objects and it seems awfully complicated to create a new one even if I try to copy most things from previous request. Do you have a snippet or some good documentation for that?

Comment: @AndersGustafsson depends a bit on your PSR7 message implementation, but the class implementing the `ServerRequestFactoryInterface::class` should allow you to create a new request object. [slim factory](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Psr7/blob/master/src/Factory/ServerRequestFactory.php#L64) if you are using slim's own implementation for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @remy stated, use the ServerRequestFactory implementing ServerRequestFactoryInterface.

For slim/psr7 it is: Slim\Psr7\Factory\ServerRequestFactory

A silent redirect to another route is then as simple as:

```
use Slim\Psr7\Factory\ServerRequestFactory;
...
...
$app->get('/foo', function ($request, $response, $args)
{
    global $app;
    return $app
        ->handle((new ServerRequestFactory())->createServerRequest('GET', '/bar'));
});
```